# Can two View Controllers have the same view?

Tags: ios, swift, view, viewcontroller

Right now in my `ViewController`, when a button is clicked, the user loads a photo from their library, and the photo is put on the canvas.

However, because I have 2 viewcontrollers, 1) `ViewController`, 2) `PhotoViewController`, the user is taken to a new blank View after after she selects a photo.

How do I get the new image added onto the main view, and take the user to there instead?

Comment: There are quite a few ways to get what you want. You can segue back to your first `ViewController` or push your `PhotoViewController` modally and dismiss it after selecting a photo. You can even add the views to a ContainerViewController and use those views however you want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to have the same view itself added to two superviews at the same time. You can obviously however have two instances of a view added to different superviews.

For your approach, consider creating a `ChosenPhoto` model which has a property for the chosen photo `UIImage`. From there, you could create a class called a `ChosenPhotoView` which displays the image contained in a `ChosenPhoto`. So between view controllers, instead of using the same view, you would just pass around persistent data which is then displayed by separate instances of views.